# window.btoa( // here programcode // ) how to do that?

Tags: javascript, window, encode

My ambition is to encode my programmcode with window.btoa(), but how can i write an string with programmcode in it - the problem is that the comipiler thinks the string is ended after the first " in the code.

example:

```js
var engine = '';


function all_this_in_the_string() {
  var examples_string = 'single';
  var double_ = "double";
}

// I have about 600 lines code with single and double quotes...of course the code is in more than one line.
// Is there a way to get this code into the string (engine) that i can encode with the line above ?

console.log(window.btoa(engine));
```

greets,
david

Comment: Then quote the code properly

Comment: Escape the quotes?

Comment: @FelixKling I edited my question, this wasn't what i searched for - thanks for the note. :)

Comment: @FelixKling and remove the marked as duplicate -.-

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `all_this_in_string.toString()`? Can't really tell. Please update the title of your question to something descriptive. I also recommend to read [ask] to learn how ask better questions.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to vary between single and double quotes.

```
var engine = 'function() { var examples_string = "here_is_the_problem"}';
```

Comment: You can also escape the quotes `'function() { var examples_string = \'here_is_the_problem\'}'`